# Loading jQuery via wp_enqueue issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having issues loading jQuery via wp_enqueue_script - I just discovered this is the correct way to pull in jQuery to avoid posible JS conflicts but I can't get it work. I'm using this example:

```
function my_init() {
   if (!is_admin()) {
  // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
  wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
  wp_register_script('jquery',   'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.3.2'); 
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

I'm getting nothing when I check my source files. From what I can see the syntax is correct, I'm attempting to do this on a local WP install using XAMPP if that matters. Has anyone run into a similar issue? I've seen several questions about this but the fix usually comes down to a syntax error. I'm not seeing one. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the code below to your theme's functions.php in place of what you have.

The version of jQuery you were trying to load was outdated by the way.

Is this a custom theme you're building? If so are you using the wp_head and wp_footer tags?

By de-registering the built in version of jQuery and loading jQuery from the Google CDN you're reducing the time it takes to download the file but it isn't necessary. You could just load jQuery with wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

```
function my_enqueue_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js', false, '2.0.3' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_jquery' );
```

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH, I was missing a step. Duh :(, I didn't know anything about wp_head and wp_footer. Reading up on that now. You're the man, thanks a bunch.

Comment: @jasenmp in nearly every situation imaginable you will need to have `wp_header();` in your `header.php` file (in the `head`) and `wp_footer();` in your `footer.php` file (beneath the HTML markup).

Comment: Ennui, yep just figured that out. Thanks!

Comment: @Ennui Please be aware the tag is wp_head(); rather than wp_header();

Comment: @NathanDawson you're right, brain fart!  It's always been a part of my starter theme I use so I don't have to think about it much.  Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress 3.8 has jQuery.1.10.3.

wp_deregister_script('jquery') is not good for site.
So, you'd rather upgrade wordpress and use higher version of jQuery included in wordpress.

Please review this [Wordpress Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/alibaba-multi-purpose-responsive-ecommerce-theme/6555177?ref=Hanatheme).

It's much easier to customize and has lots of features. Also easy to learn code tips.

Regards. HanaTheme.